# Setting Android images from string value

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

Currently I'm drawing a PNG image in my Android application like so:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.testimage))
```

If I have a list of image names in a database, is there a way to set the drawable above using the image name? I already have the code to go through the database, I'm just looking to draw the image based on the value taken from here.

For example, a record for the DB:

```
ID:    Name:    ImageName:
-      Test     testimage
```

So when I'm reading this record, I have a string with the value of "testimage" and I'd then want to set the image drawable to `R.drawable.testimage`.

One way I was thinking of doing it would be something like this:

```
int image = R.drawable.blank; // blank image

// testimage.png is the image name from the database
if(imageName.toString().equals("testimage.png"))
    image = R.drawable.testimage;
else if(imageName.toString().equals("another.png"))
    image = R.drawable.another;
else if(imageName.toString().equals("etc.png"))
    image = R.drawable.etc;
```

However this isn't very efficient!

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a method for doing that, you can retreive resource IDs by string using Resources.getIdentifier() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html

Something like:

```
int resourceId = Activity.getResources().getIdentifier("testimage", "drawable", "your.package.name");
```

Answer (score 23):

I'm using:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("testimage", "drawable", getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(resId);
```

"testimage" - corresponds to for instance testimage.jpg, i.e. dont include ".jpg"

"drawable" - is the resource type, like in: @drawable/testimage

Check [Resources.getIdentifier(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("testimage", "drawable", mainActivity.getPackageName());
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);

Comment: Boo yeah!  This was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Put you images in the assets/ folder and open

```
image.setImageURI("file:///android_asset/" + nameFromDB);
```

Answer (score -2):

String path = "sdcard/camera_app/name.jpg";
        img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));

Comment: Without any explanation, this is not helpful.

Comment: You can use path for different images example String path = "sdcard/camera_app/image1.jpg";  or String path = "sdcard/camera_app/image2.jpg"  this can be use in if else condtion to draw a image only you want.