# setImageResource from a string

Tags: java, android

I would like to change the imageview src based on my string, I have something like this:

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

String correctAnswer = "poland";
String whatEver = R.drawable+correctAnswer;
imageView1.setImageResource(whatEver);
```

Of course it doesnt work. How can I change the image programmatically?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
public static int getImageId(Context context, String imageName) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + imageName, null, context.getPackageName());
}
```

use:
 `imageView1.setImageResource(getImageId(this, correctAnswer);`

Note: leave off the extension (eg, ".jpg").

Example: image is "abcd_36.jpg"

```
Context c = getApplicationContext();
int id = c.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/"+"abcd_36", null, c.getPackageName());
((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.your_image_on_your_layout)).setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: For imagename are we going to pass full name like "news.png" or just image name without extension as "news" ? I tried both and did not work for me.

Comment: I couldn't get the following to work.

I found http://stackoverflow.com/a/4313064/2895831 which had
`int resourceId = Activity.getResources().getIdentifier("testimage", "drawable", "your.package.name");` which used "drawable" as the second parameter
`getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)`

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is what you had in mind at all, but you could set up a HashMap of image id's (which are ints) and Strings of correct answers.

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> images = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    images.put( "poland", Integer.valueOf( R.drawable.poland ) );
    images.put( "germany", Integer.valueOf( R.drawable.germany ) );

    String correctAnswer = "poland";
    imageView1.setImageResource( images.get( correctAnswer ).intValue() );
```