# Sending String's Value to a Method

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am making an Android app. I have an `ImageView` and in some part of my code, I need to change its resource. I have a String array which is

`String[] names = {"chair","desk"};`

I have 2 images in my drawable folder whose names are "chair" and "desk". When I use

`image.setImageResource(R.drawable.chair);`

it works perfectly. But I need to use it as:

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.names[0]);
```

but Java doesn't allow me to do it. I need to send the value of string to that method. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783327/setimageresource-from-a-string

Answer (score 6):

I would change it like

```
int[] names = {R.drawable.chair,R.drawable.desk};
```

and then you can use directly

```
image.setImageResource(names[0]);
```

if you want to use a `String` you can use `getResources().getIdentifier()` to retrive the id of drawable with that name

Comment: But setImageResource method gets an Integer. It displays an error when I try to send String value

Comment: that's why I changed from String[] to int[]

Comment: The R.drawable.chair/desk variables are actually generated integer IDs that point to the correct resource. It wouldn't make much sense for them to be Strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use like this way

```
String[] names = {"drawable/chair","drawable/desk"};

int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(names[0], null, getActivity().getPackageName());

image.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

Its quite simple.

Comment: This would not consider the screen resolution based image pick from the respective drawable folder (have an explanation below)

Comment: its same as use like R.drawable.chair , But this is another way to use resources in android. Its image resolution is based on imageview.

Comment: No it is not.. When you specify the drawable path as "/drawable" then the system looks for only "/drawable" folder, whereas when you reference from R.drawable.xx then the system would pick the resource from appropriate folder (it could be drawabl-hdpi or drawable-mdpi depending upon screen resolution of the mobile phone)

Comment: I tried this but got NullPointerException. I think context is null but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: @berkc put code snippet, i tested it and its working perfect!

Comment: @VishalPatel it's funny because code works on mainActivity but crashes on another activity

Comment: @berkc ok have you changed context

Answer (score 0):

Using R.drawable.xx ensures that correct image is picked from the correct folder (per se drawable/ or drawable-hdpi or drawable-mdpi) depending upon the device screen resolution. Hence using R.drawable.xx is the recommended method as Against "*getResources().getIdentifier(FixedPatch)*"

Since R.drawable.xx is a dynamically generated object, using a switch case and referencing proper drawable object based on the incoming case would work the best. Also, having a default case ensures that if an image is not found in the drawable folder still the ImageView is rendered without any issues.

E.g.,

```
Switch (Case)
  Case "myString" : ImageView.setImageResource(R.id.myString);//here R.id.myString is hardcoded object reference
  Case "myString2" : ImageView.setImageResource(R.id.myString);
  default : ImageView.setImageResource(R.id.myDefaultImage);
```