# Assign ImageView src with drawable name

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

To make things simple: I got the drawable name from a JSON file and is now in a variable, how can I assign the correct drawable to an `ImageView` with the name as a `String`? We can assume that the drawable with that name always exists.

```
String image_name = "image1.png";

ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
imageView.setImageResource(image_name); // FAIL since is expecting the drawable and not the name as a String.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783327/setimageresource-from-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imageView.setImageResource(getDrawableFromName(context,"image1.png""));

public static int getDrawableFromName(Context context, String drawableName) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable",
            context.getPackageName());
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy! this doesn't break with my logic and is more straightforward than the other answer since I don't need to create additional objects

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `String source` and get the drawable.

```
private Drawable getImage(String source){
        File imgFile = new File(source);//Absolute path
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;
        Drawable drawable = null;
        if(imgFile.exists()) {
            myBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),myBitmap);
        }
        return  drawable;
    }
```