# How to change an ImageView with a filename

Tags: android, imageview

I have a string with the name of the file that I want (R.drawable.square) to put in the imageview.

```
String shape = "square"
```

I am trying to use the method below to show the image

```
imageView.setImageResource()
```

Hardcoding the filename in works but I want to be able to pass different filenames in.

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.square)
```

tl;dr
can't get from String:"square" to int:R.drawable.square

Comment: let's try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783327/setimageresource-from-a-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, reference things in R.drawable. using variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941304/android-reference-things-in-r-drawable-using-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [Android, reference things in R.drawable. using variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941304/android-reference-things-in-r-drawable-using-variables)

```
//to retrieve image in res/drawable and set image in ImageView
String imageName = "picture"
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", "package.name");
ImageView image;
image.setImageResource(resID );
```

Comment: Citing a link is not consider the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the effect by putting the images in the assets directory

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use you Strings as key and your resource ids as value in a `Map` Object.

```
    Map<String, Integer> resources = new HashMap<>();

    resources.put("square", R.drawable.square);
    // resources.put("...", R.drawable....);

    imageView.setImageResource(resources.get("square"));
```