# android change background image programmatically from string

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting Android images from string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313007/setting-android-images-from-string-value)

I need to change background image programmatically on Android with source string I have. 
For example I have an array of strings gotten from XML file "source1", "source2" etc., so how can I set them to background as images? 
I saw examples like  `mTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myResouce);`, but I don't understand how to set mySource from a String. May be it is possible through drawable object?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313007/setting-android-images-from-string-value

Comment: Why you make text as a background..?
If you need hint then use "android:hint"...

Comment: Which type of strings are you getting from XML file? Can you show some examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep your images name inside drawables  same as of in String.xml.

**Say for eg: images.png** it should be **images** in String.xml

If you pass this name to **getResourceId()** it will returns you Drawable with that String Variable.

```
public static int getResourceId(Context context, String name, String resourceType) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, resourceType, context.getPackageName());
}

int iconId = getResourceId(Activity.this, image, "drawable");    

ImageView categoryIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);
categoryIcon.setImageResource(iconId);
```

Comment: What is toResourceString(name) method?

Comment: Check mu updated answer.No need of that method..Simply pass String name

Comment: I've tried this, but it didn`t work for me `View v = new View(this);

  TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.provider_logo);
  int resid = Helpers.getResourceId(PaymentActivity.this, "logo", "drawable");
  textView.setBackgroundResource(resid);`

Comment: You have to set Background for ImageView, why are you setting for TextView?

Comment: Yeap, works good without v in v.findViewById - answer accepted =)

Comment: Could U please explain me how to create an xml with several images? I presume that this file should be saved in drawable folder? I mean what should be the structure of an xml?

Comment: Come to chat Room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people