# Cannot assign Setimage resource Integer

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have a table in which i have one column where pictures names like `R.drawable.pic101` , `R.drawable.pic2` are saved. Now retrieving from database im storing theses names in an `ArrayList` of `String`. Now to `setImageResource` these names should be in `Integer` `ArrayList`.. Now i need to convert `ArrayList` of `String` to `ArrayList` of `Integer`. Please give me a possible solution.

Comment: please show Your code.....

Comment: have a look here on how to convert a string to a drawable resource --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313007/setting-android-images-from-string-value

Comment: BestListAdapter adapter=new BestListAdapter(FoodItem.this,images, names, calory, details,quan,chek1);
   lists=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.fooditemlist);
   
   lists.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: dont forget to remove all the (R.drawable) from your db entries as you dont need them anymore so just store the pic name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your ArrayList with resources ID as an integer, to get resources with string names you need to obtain its identifiers:

```
private Integer getResourceByString(Context context, String name) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

Or you could also set directly the desired Drawable to the ImageView:

```
private void setStringResourceImageView(ImageView imageView, String name) {
    Context context = imageView.getContext();
    Integer resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(resId);
}
```