# Setting an ImageView source from a given string array

Tags: android, arrays, string, image, android-resources

I'm creating a card game based on a Client Server communication, where the server (TV) shuffles and deals cards to players - clients (Android phones).
I'm struggling with exactly how to set the source image for my cards, client-side.
As the client I'm receiving the cards in a string array (eg. `[C1,C2,C3,C4,C5]`), note that in resources the image files are named exactly as they appear in that string (C = Clubs, D = Diamonds .. from 1 to 13). how should I do this ? I want to use the String Array in such a way that I can extract a single string and by using know which of the images I need to set as a source.

P.S I know I can use a switch with 52 cases for each source, but I'm sure there's a better way of doing things.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4313064/2435402 should be what you're looking for. Wrapping this implementation inside a helper class of some sort gives a decent OOP approach. i.e. `CardHelper.getCardFromString('...')` would return an instance of a `Card`. OOP possibilities are endless and that's the fun part :)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it helped.