# How to set image programmatically to an ImageView inside an adapter using String value?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

As mentioned in the title, I have a `RecyclerView` inside which I need to populate `20` images. Since the images are available in `drawable` I am trying to programmatically set these images from the `adapter` of `RecyclerView`.

---

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HomeTeamViewHolder homeTeamViewHolder, int i)
    {

        homeTeamViewHolder.teamName.setText(d1.teams.get(i));
        String str = "R.drawable.e0";

        homeTeamViewHolder.home_teams.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(homeTeamViewHolder.mcontext,str));

    }
```

---

Now, this obviously doesn't work as Android studio says:

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'int'

For which, a solution already exists: [Setting Android images from string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313007/setting-android-images-from-string-value)

However, when I tried:

```
    int resourceId = Activity.getResources().getIdentifier("testimage", "drawable", "your.package.name");
```

inside `onBindViewHolder()` :

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HomeTeamViewHolder homeTeamViewHolder, int i)
{

    homeTeamViewHolder.teamName.setText(d1.teams.get(i));
    //String str = "R.drawable.e0";
    int resourceId = Activity.getResources().getIdentifier("testimage", "drawable", "your.package.name");
    homeTeamViewHolder.home_teams.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(homeTeamViewHolder.mcontext,resourceId));

}
```

Android Studio says:

> Non-static method `getResources()` cannot be referenced from a static context

---

So, the **question** is: how to fix this?

Comment: you need context or activity instance to use getRestources() method. Or simply try to call getApplicationContext().getResources() if your adapter in activity

Comment: int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier("image_name", "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, iStopImageId));

Comment: instead of using String str = "R.drawable.e0"; use int img=R.drawable.e0

Comment: @Kintanpatel There is no issue with context, the problem is only at `getResources()`

Comment: @Daryl That doesn't sound feasible, as I have e0,e1,.......e20 images

Comment: then you can fix it by "Mây Và Bão" answer

Comment: You can use homeTeamViewHolder.teamName.getContext() to get the context object.

Comment: @MâyVàBão I attempted that, and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the context to the Adapter in constructor. Then you can access to getResources() through that context.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {

    ...

    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Other_arguments_you_need) {
        this.context = context;
        // set other arguments
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HomeTeamViewHolder homeTeamViewHolder, int i)
    {

        homeTeamViewHolder.teamName.setText(d1.teams.get(i));
        int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("testimage", "drawable", "your.package.name");
        homeTeamViewHolder.home_teams.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(homeTeamViewHolder.mcontext,resourceId));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by passing context to the Adapter.

```
 Context mcontext = itemView.getContext();
```

then, inside `onBindViewHolder()` :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HomeTeamViewHolder homeTeamViewHolder, int i)
{

    homeTeamViewHolder.teamName.setText(d1.teams.get(i));
    String x = "e"+i;
    int resourceId = homeTeamViewHolder.mcontext.getResources().getIdentifier(x, "drawable", "com.udacity.yaafl");
    homeTeamViewHolder.home_teams.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(homeTeamViewHolder.mcontext,resourceId));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

grab the Integer ID of a resource by this

```
  int resourceId = homeTeamViewHolder.itemView.getResources().getIdentifier("testimage", "drawable", "your.package.name");
```